# Uso de FormData(), append y axios para el formulario de creación/edición de un documento

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, laravel-6, formdata

Estoy tratando de realizar un formulario para administración de documentos, este formulario incluye campos como nombre,área,estatus,fecha...,además de un archivo. El formulario y el archivo se guardan mediante la función **registrarDocumento()** que hace uso de **axios.post**, de **FormData** y **append** para agregar el archivo y demás datos al request que es enviado al controlador de Laravel,todo esto  funciona sin ningún problema, pero al momento de querer realizar el formulario de actualización esta vez mediante **axios.put** y querer agrupar los datos de la misma forma para recibirlos en el request de Laravel, el controlador esta recibiendo un request vacío.

Estas son mis rutas en Laravel:

```
Route::post('/documento/registrar','DocumentController@store');
Route::put('/documento/actualizar','DocumentController@update');
Route::get('/documento/show/{document_id}','DocumentController@show');
```

Esta es la función de mi controlador:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
  // if (!$request->ajax()) return redirect('/');

  return $request;
}
```

Este es mi componente de Vue:

```
<template>
  <div >

   <h1>Documento: {{$route.params.document_id}}</h1>

    <!-- Formulario -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="ibox ">
          <div class="ibox-content">
            <h4>Información del Documento</h4>
            <hr>
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data">

              <div class="form-group row justify-content-end">
                <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">
                  Estatus:
                </label>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                  <select class="form-control" v-model="status_id">
                    <option value="0" disabled >Estatus</option>
                    <option v-for="estatus in arrayEstatus" :key="estatus.status_id" :value="estatus.status_id" v-text="estatus.status_name" > </option>
                  </select>
                </div>

              </div>

              <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">
                  Nombre del Documento:
                </label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" v-model="document_name" class="form-control" placeholder ="Nombre del Documento">
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">
                  Tema del Documento:
                </label>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                  <select class="form-control" v-model="theme_id">
                    <option value="0" disabled >Tema</option>
                    <option v-for="tema in arrayTema" :key="tema.theme_id" :value="tema.theme_id" v-text="tema.theme_name" > </option>
                  </select>
                </div>


                <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-center">
                  Nivel de Autorización:
                </label>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                  <select class="form-control" v-model="authorization_level_id">
                    <option value="0" disabled >Nivel de Autorización</option>
                    <option v-for="nivel in arrayNiveles" :key="nivel.authorization_level_id" :value="nivel.authorization_level_id" v-text="nivel.authorization_level_code" > </option>
                  </select>
                </div>

              </div>

              <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">
                  Tipo del Documento:
                </label>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                  <select class="form-control" v-model="type_id">
                    <option value="0" disabled >Tipo</option>
                    <option v-for="tipo in arrayTipo" :key="tipo.type_id" :value="tipo.type_id" v-text="tipo.type_name" > </option>
                  </select>
                </div>

                <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label text-center">
                  Fecha de vencimiento:
                </label>
                <div class="col-lg-3">


                  <datepicker v-model="expiration_at" :language="es"  :bootstrap-styling="true" placeholder="Selecciona una Fecha"
                  >
                  </datepicker>

                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label">
                  Área:
                </label>

                <div class="col-lg-3">
                  <v-select class="style-chooser" :options="arrayArea" v-model="area_id"  placeholder="Área"></v-select>
                </div>

                <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label text-center">
                  Alcance:
                </label>

                <div class="col-lg-3">
                  <v-select class="style-chooser" :options="arrayAlcance" v-model="scope_id"  placeholder="Alcance"></v-select>
                </div>

              </div>

              <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">
                  Nombre del Autor:
                </label>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                  <select class="form-control" v-model="employee_id">
                    <option value="0" disabled >Autor</option>
                    <option v-for="autor in arrayAutor" :key="autor.employee_id" :value="autor.employee_id" v-text="autor.employee_name" > </option>
                  </select>
                </div>

                <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label text-center" >
                  Versión:
                </label>
                  <div class="col-lg-2" >
                    <input style="margin-left:20px;" type="number" v-model="version" class="form-control" placeholder ="Versión" min="0">
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">
                  Comentarios:
                </label>
                <textarea class="form-control col-lg-8" v-model="comments" style="margin-left:15px;"  rows="3">
                </textarea>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
                <figure>
                  <embed :src="previa" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%" class="border border-primary"  v-show="mostrarEmbed" />
                  <img width="200" height="200"  alt="Vista Previa" :src="previa"  v-show="mostrarImg">
                </figure>
                <p v-show="NoMostrar"> Vista Previa No Disponible</p>
              </div>

              <div v-show="errorDocumento" class="form-group row div-error">
                <div class="text-center text-error">
                  <div v-for= "error in errorMostrarMsjDocumento" :key="error" v-text="error">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="inputfile" @change="obtenerImagen" />
                <label for="file" class="btn btn-warning">
                  Cargar Archivo <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
                </label>
              </div>

              <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">

                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-right:20px;"
                    @click="registrarDocumento()"  v-if = "flag==0">
                    <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Guardar
                  </button>

                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-right:20px;"
                    @click="actualizarDocumento()"  v-if = "flag==1">
                    <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Actualizar
                  </button>

                  <router-link :to="{name:'admindocs'}" class="btn red-bg text-white"  style="margin-right:20px;">
                    <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> Cancelar
                  </router-link>
                </div>
              </div>

            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Formulario -->


  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'
import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker'
import { es } from 'vuejs-datepicker/dist/locale'

export default
{
  components: {
    Datepicker,

  },
  data(){
    return{
      /* Idioma de datepicker*/
      es:es,
      /* Idioma de datepicker*/
      /*Variables para Formulario de documento*/
      document_id:this.$route.params.document_id,
      document_name : '',
      status_id : 0,
      theme_id : 0,
      type_id : 0,
      version : '',
      expiration_at:'',
      today:'',
      employee_id : 0,
      comments : '',
      authorization_level_id : 0,
      area_id:0,
      scope_id : 0,
      file_id : 0,
      flag:0,
      file_document:'',

      errorDocumento : 0,
      errorMostrarMsjDocumento : [],
      /*Variables para Arrays de selects*/
      arrayArea :[],
      area : {
        value:0,
        label:'',
      },
      scope : {
        value:0,
        label:'',
      },
      arrayAlcance :[],
      arrayEstatus :[],
      arrayTema :[],
      arrayTipo :[],
      arrayAutor :[],
      arrayNiveles :[],

      /* Variables para Formulario de anexos*/
      modal : 0,
      tituloModal : 'Agregar Anexos',
      tipoAccion : 0,
      errorAnexo : 0,
      errorMostrarMsjAnexo : [],
      // variables para almacenamiento y vista previa de archivo
      archivo:'',
      NoMostrar:0,
      mostrarEmbed:0,
      mostrarImg:0,
      VistaPrevia:'',
      tipo_archivo:'',
      formato_archivo:'',
      // variables para almacenamiento y vista previa de archivo
    }
  },
  computed:{
    previa(){
      return this.VistaPrevia;
    }
  },
  methods:{
    /* Funciones del selects*/
    selectScope(){
            let me=this;
            var url= '/alcance/selectScope';
            axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
                // console.log(response);
                var respuesta= response.data;
                me.arrayAlcance = respuesta.alcances;
                // console.log(me.arrayArea);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
    selectArea(){
            let me=this;
            var url= '/area/selectArea';
            axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
                // console.log(response);
                var respuesta= response.data;
                me.arrayArea = respuesta.areas;
                // console.log(me.arrayArea);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
    selectStatus(){
           let me=this;
           var url= '/estatus/selectStatus';
           axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
               // console.log(response);
               var respuesta= response.data;
               me.arrayEstatus = respuesta.estatus;
               // console.log(me.arrayEstatus);
           })
           .catch(function (error) {
               console.log(error);
           });
       },
    selectTheme(){
           let me=this;
           var url= '/tema/selectTheme';
           axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
               // console.log(response);
               var respuesta= response.data;
               me.arrayTema = respuesta.temas;
               // console.log(me.arrayArea);
           })
           .catch(function (error) {
               console.log(error);
           });
       },
    selectEmployee(){
          let me=this;
          var url= '/empleado/selectEmployee';
          axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
              var respuesta= response.data;
              me.arrayAutor= respuesta.empleados;
              // console.log(me.arrayArea);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
          });
        },
    selectLevel(){
          let me=this;
          var url= '/nivel_aut/selectLevel';
          axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
              var respuesta= response.data;
              me.arrayNiveles= respuesta.niveles;
              // console.log(me.arrayNiveles);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
          });
        },
    selectType(){
      let me=this;
      var url= '/tipo/selectType';
      axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
        var respuesta= response.data;
        me.arrayTipo = respuesta.tipos;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    },
    showDocument(){
      let me=this;
      var url= '/documento/show/' + this.document_id;
      axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
        var respuesta = response.data;
        me.document_name = respuesta.documento['document_name'];
        me.status_id =  respuesta.documento['status_id'];
        me.theme_id =  respuesta.documento['theme_id'];
        me.type_id  = respuesta.documento['type_id'];
        me.version = respuesta.documento['version'];
        me.expiration_at = respuesta.documento['expiration_at'];

        me.employee_id  = respuesta.documento['employee_id'];
        me.comments  = respuesta.documento['comments'];
        me.authorization_level_id   = respuesta.documento['authorization_level_id'];

        me.area.value = respuesta.documento['area_id'];
        me.area.label = respuesta.documento['area_name'];
        me.area_id = me.area;

        me.scope.value = respuesta.documento['scope_id'];
        me.scope.label = respuesta.documento['scope_name'];
        me.scope_id = me.scope;

        me.file_id   = respuesta.documento['file_id'];
        me.flag   = respuesta.documento['flag'];
        me.file_document   = respuesta.documento['file_document'];
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    },
    /* Funciones del selects*/

    /* Funciones del Modal*/
    ListarAnexos(){
      console.log('Listar anexos');
    },
    RegistrarAnexo(){
      console.log('registrar anexo');
    },
    abrirModal(){
      this.modal = 1;
    },
    cerrarModal(){
        this.modal=0;
        this.errorAnexo = 0;
    },
    /* Funciones del Modal*/

    /* Funciones del CRUD*/
    validarElemento(){
      this.errorDocumento = 0;
      this.errorMostrarMsjDocumento = [];
      if (!this.document_name) this.errorMostrarMsjDocumento.push("El nombre del documento no puede estar vacío");
      if (!this.expiration_at) this.errorMostrarMsjDocumento.push("El documento debe contar con fecha de vencimiento");
      if (this.version <= 0) this.errorMostrarMsjDocumento.push("La versión del documento debe ser mayor a cero");
      if (this.status_id == 0)this.errorMostrarMsjDocumento.push("El campo estatus es obligatorio");
      if (this.theme_id == 0)this.errorMostrarMsjDocumento.push("El campo tema es obligatorio");
      if (this.type_id == 0)this.errorMostrarMsjDocumento.push("El campo tipo es obligatorio");
      if (this.employee_id == 0)this.errorMostrarMsjDocumento.push("El campo autor es obligatorio");
      if (this.authorization_level_id == 0)this.errorMostrarMsjDocumento.push("El campo nivel de autorización es obligatorio");
      if (!this.archivo && this.flag == 0) this.errorMostrarMsjDocumento.push("Debe agregarse un archivo");

      if (this.area_id.value == 0)this.errorMostrarMsjDocumento.push("El campo área es obligatorio");
      if (this.scope_id.value == 0)this.errorMostrarMsjDocumento.push("El campo alcance es obligatorio");
      if (this.errorMostrarMsjDocumento.length) this.errorDocumento = 1;
      return this.errorDocumento;
    },
    obtenerImagen(e){
      let file = e.target.files[0];
      // console.log(file);
      this.archivo = file;
       let info_archivo  = file.type.split("/", 2);
       this.tipo_archivo = info_archivo[0];
       this.formato_archivo = info_archivo[1];
       // console.log(this.tipo_archivo,this.formato_archivo);
       if (this.tipo_archivo == 'image')
       {
         this.mostrarEmbed =0;
         this.NoMostrar=0;
         this.mostrarImg =1;
         this.cargarImagen(file);
       }
       else if (this.tipo_archivo == 'video' || (this.tipo_archivo == 'application' && this.formato_archivo =='pdf') || (this.tipo_archivo == 'text' && this.formato_archivo =='plain')) {
         this.mostrarImg =0;
         this.NoMostrar=0;
         this.mostrarEmbed =1;
         this.cargarImagen(file);
       }
       else {
         this.mostrarImg =0;
         this.mostrarEmbed =0;
         this.NoMostrar=1;
       }
    },
    cargarImagen(file){
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (e)=>{
        this.VistaPrevia = e.target.result;
      }
     reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    },
    registrarDocumento(){
       if (this.validarElemento()) {
         return;
       }
       else {
         let me = this;
         var request = new FormData();
         request.append('documento',this.archivo)
         request.append('document_name',this.document_name)
         request.append('status_id',this.status_id)
         request.append('theme_id',this.theme_id)
         request.append('type_id',this.type_id)
         request.append('version',this.version)
         request.append('expiration_at',this.expiration_at)
         request.append('employee_id',this.employee_id)
         request.append('comments',this.comments)
         request.append('authorization_level_id',this.authorization_level_id)
         request.append('area_id',this.area_id.value)
         request.append('scope_id',this.scope_id.value)

         axios.post('/documento/registrar',request)
         .then(res=>{
           const swalWithBootstrapButtons = Swal.mixin(
           {
             customClass: {
               confirmButton: 'btn btn-success',
               cancelButton: 'btn btn-danger'
             },
             buttonsStyling: false
           })
           swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire(
             'Guardado!',
             'El documento ha sido guarado con éxito',
             'success'
           )
           this.$router.push({ name: 'admindocs' });

         })
         .catch(function (error) {
           console.log(error);
         });
       }
    },
    actualizarDocumento(){
      if (this.validarElemento()) {
        return;
      }
      else {
        let me = this;
        const request = new FormData();
        request.append('document_id',this.document_id)
        request.append('documento',this.archivo)
        request.append('document_name',this.document_name)
        request.append('status_id',this.status_id)
        request.append('theme_id',this.theme_id)
        request.append('type_id',this.type_id)
        request.append('version',this.version)
        request.append('expiration_at',this.expiration_at)
        request.append('employee_id',this.employee_id)
        request.append('comments',this.comments)
        request.append('authorization_level_id',this.authorization_level_id)
        request.append('area_id',this.area_id.value)
        request.append('scope_id',this.scope_id.value)

        axios.put('/documento/actualizar',update )

        .then(function (response) {
          const swalWithBootstrapButtons = Swal.mixin(
          {
            customClass: {
              confirmButton: 'btn btn-success',
              cancelButton: 'btn btn-danger'
            },
            buttonsStyling: false
          })
          swalWithBootstrapButtons.fire(
            'Guardado!',
            'El documento ha sido actualizado con éxito',
            'success'
          )
          this.$router.push({ name: 'admindocs' });
        })
        .catch(function (error) { console.log(error); });

      }

    },
    /* Funciones del CRUD*/
  },
  mounted(){
   this.selectArea();
   this.selectScope();
   this.selectStatus();
   this.selectTheme();
   this.selectType();
   this.selectEmployee();
   this.selectLevel();
   if(this.document_id != 0)
   {
     this.showDocument();
   }
  }

}

</script>



<style>
  .modal-content{
      width: 100% !important;
      position: absolute !important;
  }
  .mostrar{
      display: list-item !important;
      opacity: 1 !important;
      position: absolute !important;
      background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3) !important;
  }
  .div-error{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
  }
  .text-error{
      color: red !important;
      font-weight: bold;
  }

  .inputfile {
    width: 0.1px;
    height: 0.1px;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
  }

     .inputfile + label {
      color: white;
      display: inline-block;
  }
  .inputfile + label {
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .style-chooser .vs__search::placeholder,
  .style-chooser .vs__dropdown-toggle,
  .style-chooser .vs__dropdown-menu {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    border: none;
    color: black;
    /* text-transform: lowercase;
    font-variant: small-caps; */
  }

  .style-chooser .vs__clear,
  .style-chooser .vs__open-indicator {
    fill: gray;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Pero si en tu funcion update el `FormData` es `request` y tu haces la petición con una variable `update` que ni siquiera esta creada.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando envíes con Axios un documento añádele el header.

```
let opciones = {
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=${form._boundary}'}
};

axios.put(ruta,formulario,opciones)
.then(...)
```